# Printing remotly from your iPhone or IPad using an app

Tags: printing

I want to print stuff from my iPhone or IPad. My printer is connected to a PC. I saw there is an app called [PrintCentral](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/printcentral/id366020849?mt=8) that after configuration should do the trick. It is a bit pricey, so I want to know:

a) Is PrintCentral a good app? 
b) Is there a free or cheaper alternative?

EDIT: My PC is running Windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FingerPrint](http://www.collobos.com/) (OS X & Windows) is a paid application that enables a printer connected to your Mac or PC to become an AirPrint printer. It is a paid application.

**For Windows**

There is also [a free program for Windows](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1293865). You can download the files [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1293865). One they are downloaded, unzip the zip file and run the `AirPrint_Installer.exe` Then run either `AirPrint iOS 5 FIX - 32Bit.reg` or `AirPrint iOS 5 FIX - 64Bit.reg` depending on if you are running a 32 or a 64 bit version of Windows. Go back to `AirPrint_Installer.exe`, make sure "Service Startup" is set to "Auto" and click "Start". Reboot your computer. All these instructions and troubleshooting instructions can be found in the links above.

**For Mac**

[AirPrint Activator](http://netputing.com/airprintactivator/) is a free application that allows you to turn any shared printer into an Airprint printer. I have used it quite a bit now, and I highly recommend it. It has a very simple and easy to use UI:

[image: Airprint Activator]

Comment: My PC is running windows so I can not use this software.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will do a little more research and find some Windows software.

Comment: @idober See updated answer. I left AirPrint Activator in my answer, because it could be helpful for others.